Where does homebrew installs rbenv on macOS 14.6?
% ls -la ~/.rbenv
ls: /Users/`whoami`/.rbenv: No such file or directory

% ls -la  /usr/local/rbenv 
ls: /usr/local/rbenv: No such file or directory

I also get this utterly useless output from homebrew
% /opt/homebrew/bin/brew info rbenv
==> rbenv: stable 1.3.0 (bottled), HEAD
Ruby version manager
https://rbenv.org
Installed
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.3.0 (36 files, 73.6KB) *
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2024-10-03 at 19:06:03
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/r/rbenv.rb
License: MIT
==> Dependencies
Required: ruby-build ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
zsh completions have been installed to:
  /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Analytics
install: 69,942 (30 days), 212,547 (90 days), 336,817 (365 days)
install-on-request: 69,903 (30 days), 212,173 (90 days), 335,926 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)

(Lots of expletives here snipped)
I (think I) don't a million version of ruby lying around. Could I just trash 3.6.0 in favor of 3.7.4 I need for my purposes and thusly avoid this rbenv mess?
Thanks!

Surprise surprise: right next to homebrew itself in

/opt/homebrew/bin

If I were a little less lazy and added that to PATH after installing homebrew itself would've saved myself quite a bit of trouble cause I spent
and hour at least researching this before giving up and making a post here only to get an epiphany a few moments later. Ugh.
